# Laravel and polymorphic

Tags: php, orm, laravel

I try for the first polymorphic relationships and I managed to record what I think is my pivot entry.

I have a basic "Brands" as Nike or Philips, a "Valeur" as quality or compliance and classic "Users" base.

I also have a " Valuables" which is supposed to contain the input value of a "Brands" by User, I therefore structure of the database :

```
id
valeur_id (integer)
user_id (integer)
valuable_id (integer)
valuable_type (string)
```

With my little knowledge, I can save an entry with the correct value of good brand but not the id of the user.

Value model

```
public function brand ( $user )
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(' Brand', ' valuable ');
}
```

Brand model

```
public function valeur()
{
    return $this->morphToMany( 'Valeur ', ' valuable ');
}
```

I record my entry like this:

```
Brand::where( 'slug', $search)->first();
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$valeur = Valeur::find(3);

$brand->valeur()->save( $valeur );
```

I want to "just" the associated valeur -> Brand with a user id , you could please help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an array as the second argument to `save`, with data to store in the pivot table:

```
$brand->valeur()->save($valeur, array('user_id' => $id));
```

Comment: Ok, just easy ^^
Thank you.